# WPF Datagrid -- editable combobox with multi-line capability?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, multiline

In my grid I have a column which needs to provide a basic set of dropdown options, but which the user can manually edit.  I've got this part working just fine:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultComments}" Text="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Name="CommentComboBox" Loaded="CommentComboBox_Loaded" Height="50"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The additional feature I'd like to provide is to allow multi-line text entry where the user can force a line feed using Ctrl-Enter.

Is it possible to extend the existing column to do this by perhaps manipulating the TextBox portion of the ComboBox?  Or will it require a completely different template column?

Answer (score 0):

Try This below will allow you to add multiline input in textbox inside a combobox.

Add the style to the Resources

This will work for Enter rather than using Ctrl-Enter.

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyComboVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">                        
                    <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCombo}"/>
</Grid>
```

### VM

```
public class MyComboVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Texts> MyCombo { get; set; }        
    public MyComboVM()
    {
        MyCombo = new ObservableCollection<Texts>();
        MyCombo.Add(new Texts() { Text = "This is one" });
        MyCombo.Add(new Texts() { Text = "This is Two" });
    }        
}

public class Texts
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```